# How can I tell Resharper to format these field attributes differently?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, code-formatting

When I use Resharper's Code-Cleanup, this is what it does to my backing fields...

`[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)] private readonly DateTime_auctionOn;`

^ all on a single line.

How can I tell R# that I want it to be formatted like this:

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
private readonly DateTime _auctionOn;
```

please.

with cherries on top.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look under `Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Line Breaks and Wrapping` in the options and take a look at the following entries. specifically this one: `Place field attribute on same line`

[image: Place field attribute on same line]

Comment: Sad that you can't configure that for different attributes. I want stuff like `[CanBeNull]` and `[NotNull]` on the same line, while the attribute OP has posted totally belongs on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Resharper Options → `Code Editing` → `Code Cleanup` and now you need to add your own Code Cleanup profile (as MyProfile in screen shot) and set rules as you required, and save the profile. (**Keep Un-check Reformat Code**)
[image]

One thing more, you need to select your custom profile while cleanup

[image]